# How to separate two variables with a hyphen using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url

I'm trying to do some url like that: domain.com/category-subcategory.
If I go to domain.com/category Its work, but if I trying to go to domain.com/category-subcategory it is not working..
this is my code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ category.php?category=$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)-([^/]+)/$ category.php?category=$1&subcategory=$2 [L,NC]
```

How can I fix it? Thanks

**Edit:** I fixed it! here is the code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)-([^/]+)$ category.php?category=$1&subcategory=$2 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ category.php?category=$1 [L,NC]
```

I was only need to remove the slash before the $ at the end. Thanks for everyone!

Comment: I don't know .htaccess very well, but could this be an ordering issue?  It might be that the "hit" is taking on your first rule, and if you moved the order of rules, then the first would only "hit" if there's a hyphen in the name...otherwise, fall back to the other rule?

Comment: @theGleep I dont know too man, I'm trying the code I wrote, you didn't know what can I do?

Comment: Sorry it didn't work.  I'm out of ideas, then :)

Comment: @theGleep its ok dude, thanks for trying

Answer (score 0):

Try with below,

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)-([^/]+)$ category.php?category=$1&subcategory=$2 [L,NC]
```